# Dynamically adding tabs from webservice

Tags: android, web-services, rest, tabs

I would like to know the best practice for adding tabs on an android activity, where the number of tabs and it's id are coming from a webservice. For instance, on my Activity I will call a webservice to get the list of categories (which can be of any number), after that the categories will become the tabs on the activity.

I know how to use tabs using fragments, but when I dynamically get the data, I am confused on how to implement this practice.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to add to the tablayout

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourTabLayout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
```

to remove use

```
 tabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
```

to get a tab use

```
 tabLayout.getTabAt (position);
```

Comment: So, get the number of tabs from webservice, loop it to add with respect to its name ?

Comment: Yes, you can use for loop from the webservice

Comment: how can you send an ID to the tab from the Activity? Is it similar to Intent ?

Comment: you can use setTag() method to hold the id for the tab and use getTag() to get the id

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it.